# How to programmatically delete or rename an Azure Active Directory?

Tags: azure, active-directory, azure-active-directory

I have accidentally created an Azure Active Directory with the wrong name.

Using the management console, I could not find a way to correct it... I was wondiering if there is some kind of hidden API with which you this can be done?

Comment: What do you mean by "directory"? Blob container?

Comment: Edited the question. It is an active directory

Comment: Excuse me guys, but why is this question off topic?

Comment: @vainolo, i have vote to reopen, and also edited the question so it will be there in reopen queue, i guess it will open soon :)

Comment: Change it to, how to programmatically delete or rename ... so it's not an "IT" question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The delete directory functionality was added to the portal recently. Tried finding a powershell or api to do this, but doesn't seem to exist.

Answer (score 13):

Once created you can't delete a Windows Azure Active Directory.

This is the current state of the service. The irritating part is that you also can't create new one. Hopefully we will soon see at least "rename" option.

**UPDATE**

Around November 2013 (roughly 6 months after original question and answer!) Rename of Azure AD was added along with possibility to more than one Azure AD to an Azure Subscription. More details can be read on [this blog post](http://blogs.technet.com/b/ad/archive/2013/11/08/creating-and-managing-multiple-windows-azure-active-directories.aspx).

Around May 2014 (more than 1 year after original question and answer!) Delete of Windows Azure Active directory was added. More details can be read in [this blog post](http://www.edutech.me.uk/active-directory/how-to-delete-windows-azure-active-directory-waad/).

As of Late September 2014 (more than one and a half years after the original question and answer!) there is still no API to rename or delete AD. Thus no programmatic way to perform these actions.

Comment: That sucks, you know :(

Comment: You can (I just tried it) rename the Directory object. Still can't delete them.

Comment: Valuable information! Microsoft is improving the platform every single day and my hope has become true. Now waiting for the delete feature. Probably you can delete a tenant via a support request.

Comment: You can now create multiple directories. Hope the delete directory feature comes soon though...

Comment: See my new answer. The functionality was added recently, but still no APIs.

Answer (score 0):

If you want still change it and you don't need to do it programatically you can do it in [azure portal](https://manage.windowsazure.com).

I did it few minutes ago following instructions in this [article](http://blogs.technet.com/b/ad/archive/2013/11/08/creating-and-managing-multiple-windows-azure-active-directories.aspx)

> To change the name of a directory, open the management portal, click
>   on Active Directory in the left navigation bar, and click on the name
>   of the directory that you want to rename.
>
> Then, click on the CONFIGURE tab, and enter the new name for the
>   directory in the directory properties section, and click the SAVE
>   button in the command bar at the bottom of the screen.